# Curl alternative on windows to get header information

Tags: windows, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [wget/cURL alternative native to Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/299754/wget-curl-alternative-native-to-windows)

Is there any tool (command line tool preferred) to get the HTTP request header information on Windows machine like Curl does on Linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

not really.  However, you can use curl under cygwin on windows, or even use the native dos/windows clients to suit your needs. http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

Answer (score 3):

For simple operations, you can use a simple `telnet`. And write the HTTP protocol by hand. Oh the joys of plain-text protocols :)

```
telnet google.com 80

Trying 209.85.149.105...
Connected to google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: google.com

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2011 20:58:48 GMT
Expires: Thu, 12 May 2011 20:58:48 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
Server: gws
Content-Length: 219
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
^C
Connection closed by foreign host.
```