# Wget/cURL alternative native to Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, wget, curl

Is there a [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) or cURL type command line utility native to [Windows Vista](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista)? How does it work?

Comment: Even Microsoft distributes `wget.exe` in the IIS Administration Pack.

Comment: Duplicates the mis-titled ["DOS Downloaders / Downloads Managers (e.g. WGET) any more?"](http://superuser.com/questions/298020/).

Comment: Using curl just for downloading things is like using vim just for the regex feature and then saying a question about vim is a duplicate to a question about regexes. Yes downloading data files is a huge part of HTTP but it's not its main purpose.

Comment: October 2017 with Windows 8.1:  wget and curl are included in PowerShell, as shown here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364752/equivalent-of-wget-command-line-for-windows-8-1/46742133#46742133

Comment: No, *nix versions of `wget` and `curl` are not included in PowerShell. The PowerShell `Invoke-WebRequest` cmdlet is aliased as both `wget` and `curl`. It works similarly for very basic requests, but has substantially different parameters.

Comment: Check: https://curl.se/windows/

Answer (score 39):

Native to Windows (comes preinstalled and depends on the [Background Intelligent Transfer Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service) (BITS) Windows service):

**[BITSAdmin](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/bits/bitsadmin-tool)**

It can do what Wget does, and probably more (you can control an ongoing job via API-like commands - for example you can get the status speed and cancel if it is too slow).

Example usage from my own experience (you can do parallel downloads in the same .bat, or do sequential downloads in the same job):

```
bitsadmin /create thisissomejobname

bitsadmin /addfile thisissomejobname http://kakao.ro/Pictures.iso C:\john_pictures.iso

bitsadmin /SetCredentials thisissomejobname Server BASIC somehttpuser somehttppassword

bitsadmin /resume thisissomejobname

REM how to get status:
bitsadmin /info thisissomejobname
```

Note: It works on Windows XP, 7, 8 & 10 (tested on Windows 10 Pro).
On Windows XP it must be installed manually from the SP2 *Support Tools*.

On the latest Windows 10 the deprecation warning is gone, so it looks like this useful tool is here to stay.

Comment: check out /SetNotifyCmdLine option if you need to use this command sequentially in a .bat

Comment: Running bitsadmin under Windows 7 displays the following warning:  `BITSAdmin is deprecated and is not guaranteed to be available in future versions of Windows.
Administrative tools for the BITS service are now provided by BITS PowerShell cmdlets.` Users beware.

Comment: "Administrative tools for the BITS service are now provided by BITS PowerShell cmdlets." Nothing much to be beware of. Only the BITS client is deprecated, while the BITS service will remain. It will be accessible with another, similar in functionality, client (PowerShell will come preinstalled with future versions of Windows).

Comment: Note: The bitsadmin client is present in Windows 8, with the same deprecation warning.

Comment: not available on XP either: "'bitsadmin' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: This looks like the alternative to a download manager, not to a HTTP request crafter, doesn't it?

Comment: With powershell 3+ one can do `wget -outf index.html http://superuser.com` (Note there also the `curl` alias). From this [answer](http://superuser.com/a/747044/115951)

Comment: Does it work with sites that require authentication (involves cookies)?

Comment: @Brice It seems wget and aliases do not work anymore in the most recent versions of Windows (Server), unless you initialize Internet Explorer by opening it at least once.

Comment: Nice, but it doesn't seem to be able to call SOAP web services, like Curl can...

Comment: `Unable to add file to job - 0x80070057`

Answer (score 32):

PowerShell v3 CTP1 comes with a command like wget/curl. It's called [Invoke-WebRequest](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx). To learn more, you can visit the post *[Windows Powershell V3 includes command like wget/curl](http://rambletech.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/windows-powershell-v3-includes-command-like-wgetcurl/)*.

Comment: I see both http://superuser.com/a/25540/106977 and http://superuser.com/a/330754/106977 refer to Powershell commands. I have not tried either of them, but those links are related to this posting.

Comment: This is a great utility and comes with Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: [It is also possible with PowerShell 2.0](http://superuser.com/questions/299754/wget-curl-alternative-native-to-windows/494003#494003).

Comment: As I know, `Invoke-WebRequest` can't ignore certificate errors (a very useful feature for developers). At least in version 3.0

Comment: I can't get `Invoke-WebRequest` to ignore certificate errors in PowerShell 5.1, but the documentation in PowerShell 6 includes a `SkipCertificateCheck` flag: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6

Comment: @Brice It seems wget and aliases do not work anymore in the most recent versions of Windows (Server), unless you initialize Internet Explorer by opening it at least once.

Answer (score 15):

I often use PowerShell for simple things, like [WebClient's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [DownloadString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144200%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
$wc = New-Object Net.WebClient
$wc.DownloadString('...')
```

Or [`DownloadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144194%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want something downloaded like `wget` does and package that off into a function. Of course, this is *very* rough and won't have any of the niceties like resumable downloads and similar.

Comment: Using `DownloadFile`. it worked when I tried it (PowerShell 2.0): `$wc.DownloadFile('http://traffic.libsyn.com/makingembeddedsystems/embedded-ep149.mp3', 'EmbeddedFm_149.mp3')`. However, there is no progress information duríng the download.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: Of course not. It's just a .NET object. You can attach an event handler to `DownloadProgressChanged`, though. But I guess then you'll also need to use the async variants of the methods.

Answer (score 9):

It seems you only need to download an alternative browser. You can use this command to download Mozilla Firefox with the command prompt:

```
explorer.exe http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/6.0.2/win32/en-US/Firefox%20Setup%206.0.2.exe
```

This also launches Internet Explorer, but only with a basic feature set. This should work even if Internet Explorer is broken (in most cases).

You can also use the FTP command. Type the following into the command prompt commands:

1. Type `FTP` - Which opens the FTP client
2. Type `open ftp.mozilla.org` - Which connects to Mozilla-FTP
3. Just login as *Anonymous* and use an empty password.
4. Type `cd /pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/4.0.1/win32/en-US/` -To change the directory
5. Type `recv "Firefox Setup 4.0.1.exe"` - To download the Firefox installer. The file is located in the current folder of the command prompt. (usually your `Profile` folder)
6. Type `bye` to close the FTP client
7. Type `exit` to close the command prompt.

Comment: Nice answer, but completely unrelated to the question asked.

Comment: Um.  Seems both topical and an example of using explorer.exe as an alternative.

Comment: First way error `Unable to launch Microsoft Edge.` while it is not installed, Second way will freeze after `open` command

Answer (score 7):

There is no Wget alternative really. You can use [Wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) and assign the path in your environment variables to get it working how you want.

Comment: The problem is, the person I'm working with is getting a browser freeze on launch, and they have no access to another computer.

Comment: If they're running through ethernet, get them to boot into safe mode with networking?

Answer (score 3):

Native cURL for Windows is available [here](http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?search=curl&function=search). There are many flavors available- with SSL support, without SSL support. You don't need the extra baggage of [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) and the likes, just one small EXE file.

Comment: Great, here's also probably a similar (or the same?) one: https://curl.se/windows/

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) and install the wanted libraries... I have always done that...

In the past, I searched for alternatives, yes. But Cygwin is just the best tool for the job.

Comment: Except it is overkill installing the gazillions of files for a typical Cygwin installation just to get Wget.

Comment: You get wget, curl, ... and much more. I suppose if you need wget you will probably use some additional linux tools in the future :) - definatly not an every day screnario though

Answer (score 1):

I've created my own. Check it out at https://github.com/acarrilho/global (at the bottom of the page).

Download the source and, using cmd.exe, navigate to the requester folder. From there, just type `http` to see all the settings available. As an example:

```
http -u "http://www.example.com" -oc
```